# Adding git repository with yarn results in error

Tags: yarnpkg

I am just learning about yarn and npm.

I want to use a particular package that crashes my app.  I found a project issue which looks like fix has been implemented and merged with master.  A comment says npm package has not been updated yet.

I have added the package to my project:
yarn add react-widgets

I thought I could use yarn to add the package via git repository to get fixed version.

The package I want is 
https://github.com/jquense/react-widgets

So I tried 
yarn add https://github.com/jquense/react-widgets.git

I get error:
error Package "undefined@undefined" doesn't have a "name".

Firstly, is this error a problem with my use of yarn or a problem with react-widgets repository?  I am assuming it should work to add it like this so please correct me if I am wrong.

Also, can I assume that if there is an updated npm package, that I will be able to update with yarn at that time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid it is impossible to do now. This git repo is actually several packages inside(main package is [here](https://github.com/jquense/react-widgets/tree/master/packages/react-widgets)) one repo and root `package.json` is not valid one - it doesn't have name description and this is fail reason. [There is](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/4725) discussion about supporting this in yarn, but it hasn't been implemented yet(in npm too).